# show decimal using C

Tags: c

I'm trying to show the decimal points after the number

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int weight;
    int miles;
    int price;

    printf("Enter the packages weight \n");
    scanf("%d", &weight);

    printf("Enter how many miles to ship the package \n");
    scanf("%d", &miles);

    if(weight <= 15) {
        price = 15;
    }
    else {
        price = (15 + ((weight - 15) * .5 ));
    }
    if(miles % 500 == 0) {
        price += (miles / 500 * 10);
    }
    else {
        price += ((miles / 500 )* 10) + 10;
    }


    printf("It will cost $%d to ship an item weighing %d pounds %d miles \n", price, weight, miles);
    return 0;
}
```

for the `price = (15+((weight-15)*.5));` When I plug in the numbers outside of the console it shows the decimal places. I'm probably missing the most simple thing...

Comment: yes, use a `double`.

Comment: Also in your `printf` don't use `%d` when you want to print floating point numbers, use `%f`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Never use floating point for currencies or other exact calculations.

Comment: @Olaf Agree, but I don;t know whether OP is bothered about accuracy or not. It seems to be a very prelim problem.

Comment: Rolled back. Do not change the question such that it leaves answers without context!

Comment: @SouravGhosh: To me the question is not clear. But I agree OP seems to have fundamental problems, not only the datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the data type of the variable `price` to `float` (or `double`) if you wish to store some fractional part in it.

Also, since `miles / 500` may create some decimal part (and `miles` itself can be floating-point!), it should also be made `float` or `double`.

Finally, in the `printf` arguments, do not forget to change the format specifier `%d`.

Prefer to use a floating-point data type for all the variables involved in some computation that might yield fractional numbers as it will be more comprehensible and if you wish to not see the decimal part in the output, then set the precision to 0 (`%.0f`).

Comment: He definitely should [not](http://ideone.com/6X8ope) do that. Unless you think it's sane to have 3.65 plus 0.05 not equal to 3.70!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: But we can take the difference of the expressions we want to compare and see if it is very small or not.